# Access to variable defined in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular

In index.html i add script and create object

```
       <script>
            let dkrm = new Darkroom('#ocrImg', {
                // Size options
                minWidth: 800,
                minHeight: 800,
                maxWidth: 1000,
                maxHeight: 900,
                ratio: 4/3,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
            });
        </script>
```

but now i try use this Darkroom in some component in Angular ts file

I try

```
var declare Darkroom: any;
```

and in

```
    ngOnInit() { this.darkroom = window["dkrm"];}
```

but this.darkroom is undefined

How to get access to variable defined in index.html and use this var in .ts file?

Comment: Declare the variable with `var`, not `let`.

Comment: In the component file: `declare var dkrm: any;`, and then use `dkrm` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to set field of `window` directly

```
<script>
    window.dkrm = new Darkroom('#ocrImg', {
        // Size options
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 800,
        maxWidth: 1000,
        maxHeight: 900,
        ratio: 4/3,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable defined with a let in a script tag.

If you want to define a global variable, you must put it in the window object:

```
<script>
        window.dkrm = new Darkroom('#ocrImg', {
            // Size options
            minWidth: 800,
            minHeight: 800,
            maxWidth: 1000,
            maxHeight: 900,
            ratio: 4/3,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your data to window object (e.g. window.darkroom) and access it in your component below.

index.html

```
<script>
    window.darkroom = {};
</script>
```

component.ts

```
darkroom: Object = {};
ngOnInit() {
    this.darkroom = window.darkroom;
}
```

Comment: Try this and i have error Property 'darkrom' does not exist on type '<T>(this: Observable<T>, windowBoundaries: Observable<any>) => Observable<Observable<T>>'